# Arrays in stacks in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stack, queue

I want to stack or queue arrays/vectors in c++.

I've tried multiple variants, including with vectors, but unsuccessful. I thought this would be a quite "standard" problem, but cannot fint resources on it.
Here is one suggested implementation of queuing vectors, but compilation doesn't like it.

```
#include <queue> 
queue<int[2]> q; 
q.push({9,3});
q.push({5,2});
```

Comment: Use `std::array<int, 2>` instead of `int[2]`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it.

Comment: queue<vector<int>> / stack<vector<int>>

Comment: You should not be having any issue if you replaced `queue<int[2]>` in this code with `queue<vector<int>>`. You must have made a different mistake when trying that. If the elements are always supposed to have size `2`, `queue<array<int, 2>>` may be preferred though.

Comment: Thanks guys! Solved. But cannot close the question before three minutes apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `q.push({9,3});` does not work because C-style array does not have initialise-list constructor.

One solution is to use std::array instead of C-style array as the type of your queue:

```
#include <array>

std::queue<std::array<int, 2>> q; 
q.push({9,3});
q.push({5,2});
```

Comment: Also c-style arrays are not copyable or assignable.